# Connecting to MS SQLServer from a Linux box

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, sql-server, kerberos

I am trying to connect to MS SQLServer from an application that I have written (using Qt) which runs on Linux.  Here are some details of the setup:

The SQLServer box  (SQLBox) is part of my domain (`mydomain.local`).
This domain uses Active Directory running on `ADBox.mydomain.local`,
The Linux box is not part of the domain.
The user on the Linux box is logged on locally. ie `mvincent@linuxbox`.

I have installed Kerberos on Linux and configured it to connect to `ADBox.mydomain.local`.
Using `kinit mvincent@mydomain.local` I get a ticket returned which can be seen using `klist`.
`mvincent@mydomain.local` is setup with permissions to access SQLServer on SQLBox.

I am using ODBC to connect to SQLServer.
SQLServer is configuered to accept connections only from ActiveDirectory users.  A user name and password cannot be used to connect to the SQLServer.
My ODBC connection string includes `Trusted_Connection=yes`.

My Qt application will run as the logged on user on Linux.  This will be mvincent.LinuxBox.  I can't get a ticket for this user, so the connection is refused.

I can get a ticket for `mvincent@mydomain.local`, but I can't figure out how to enter this ticket or this user into the ODBC connection string.

How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [using the sqlcmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connecting-with-sqlcmd) command. The utility is available in the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux.

Comment: and you must know many parameter effect on kerberos ... also you can see http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/kerberos.html                          http://jensd.be/255/linux/execute-queries-on-a-microsoft-sql-server-from-the-linux-cli-with-odbc-and-kerberos-authentication

Comment: @Mohammad_moeini  Thank you.  Can you explain how sqlcmd will work in my Qt application?  Regards, Mike

Comment: @Mohammad_moeini  thanks for the links - I have seen them already, but they don't address my situation. Regards, Mike

Comment: refrence of sqlcmd at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx    and also you can run a command in qt with qprocess for more info see : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html

Comment: Thank you.  Reading that and your previous link I can't see how that will help me to connect to SQLServer from within my Qt application.  Can you explain, please?